# Celery Task.delay behavior

Tags: python, rabbitmq, celery, amqp

Is it possible that Task.delay just silently gets killed under high throughput scenario? I am using Celery with RabbitMQ as backend. Do not understand its internals fully and how does celery controls the behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The time limit (–time-limit) is the maximum number of seconds a task may run before the process executing it is terminated and replaced by a new process.

http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/workers.html#time-limits